# Audio feedback in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: logging, ubuntu, terminal, tail, beep

I would like to find a way to get my terminal to give audio feedback whenever new input is delivered to the terminal.

Here's the scenario.  At my desk, I have a monitoring machine set up that has various Munin and NewRelic dashboards.  I'm also tailing a few logs in Terminal, some with specific greps.  I would like to find a way to have the terminal play a sound when one of these tail'd logs is updated.

For example:

```
tail -f /var/log/myservice.log | grep "CRITICAL" | beep
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most terminals (can be configured) to beep when a `^G` character is displayed; that is the ASCII `BEL` character.

You can generate the `BEL` character with an `echo -e '\a'` command or something similar. With a slight change of your script, you ought to be able to do this easily:

```
tail -f /var/log/myservice.log | sed 's/CRITICAL/CRITICAL\a/'
```

Most terminals will *also* set the Urgent flag on the window in question, which should make it easy to discover the specific terminal that requires attention even when on another desktop.

Comment: I like this answer best b/c it relies on existing tools to get the job done simply.  The other answers are also viable.

Answer (score 1):

in `konsole` you can tell it to monitor a terminal for activity, and you can configure what notifications to use (sound, popup, run command...).

Answer (score 1):

This is how to play sound every time that some file changes:

`while true; do inotifywait /var/log/myservice.log && mplayer /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg; done`

Press Ctrl+C to interrupt. You need to install package `inotify-tools` and `mplayer` (can be replaced with any other console player).

If you still want to see tail output, run tail in another tab.

Comment: I really like that use of `inotify-tools`.